# Secondary Navigation Menudisappeared When using wp_nav_menu_items

Tags: menus, filters

My Secondary Navigation Menu works fine until I use add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items') to add a login / logout button to my primary menu.
Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
 function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
//Add item to primary menu
if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {

    //checks if user is logged in
   if (is_user_logged_in()) {
       //builds menu item and sub items
    $items .= '<li id="menu-item-portal" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">'.
   // $submenus .
    //Sub Items
    '<ul class="sub-menu">' .
    //FAQ
        '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-232">'.
            '<a href="' . get_site_url() . '/portal/Faq">'.
                '<span>FAQ</span>' .
            '</a>'.
        '</li>'.
        // Contacts
        '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-232">'.
            '<a href="' . get_site_url() . '/portal/Contacts">'.
                '<span>TeAHN Contacts</span>' .
            '</a>'.
        '</li>'.
        //Bulletin
         '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-232">'.
            '<a href="'. get_site_url() . '/portal/Bulletin">'.
                '<span>Bulletin</span>' .
            '</a>'.
        '</li>'.
        // Documents
          '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-232">'.
            '<a href="'. get_site_url() . '/portal/Documents">'.
                '<span>Documents</span>' .
            '</a>'.
        '</li>'.
        //Logout
        '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-232">'.
            '<a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">'.
                '<span>Log Out</span>' .
            '</a>'.
        '</li>'.

    '</ul>'.



    '<a href="'.  get_site_url() . '/portal">Portal</a></li>';
}
elseif (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $items .= '<li id="menu-item-login"><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
}
return $items;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `return $items;` outside of the `if` check. Currently, you are only returning menu items when the theme location is `primary`, all other menus will have no menu items if you return nothing for those.